# Apache file caching after editing by ftp

Tags: php, apache, caching, ftp

I am experiencing this strange behaviour, on a shared hosting I am connected by FTP and when I am editing some file(and saving it), it takes at least a few minutes for that change to take effect. For example  I put in my `index.php` file the line `echo "test";die;`and save it: the program (I am using file zilla) shows that the file is uploaded into server. just in case to be sure, am doing `cat index.php` (im connected by putty) and I can see that the change in fact is done. But, guess what, when I open in the browser it just works as before (without showing my "test"). But I just wait a few minutes and refresh the page it shows me that "test". Browser cache I deleted(though do not think it matters this case, also trying to refresh the page by CTRL+F5) but after all only after a few minutes changes take into effect. The same thing when I delete that line and double check that it is saved, again during a few minute still I see that echo, when when is nothing in the file already.

So, is there such a thing, that apache has some kind of cache, so even if I change the files in a physical drive after all it uses the file from there and only after a few minutes updates the cache ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you do e.g. `index.php?a=1`, then change the file and do `index.php?a=2` ? (this isn't a solution, just working through it)

Comment: actually it will not really be a solution, because it is not just about index.php, I just brought example to be a simple description.  thanks

Comment: can you provide your headers received by your browser?

Comment: @dav the idea of the test was to see how the file is being cached, so we can narrow down what is caching it. So just add ?a=1 to WHATEVER PAGE you have.

Comment: @cmorrissey, here http://s23.postimg.org/o8om9qsjf/header_list.png

Comment: @rjdown, I tried, the same. I mean even if I edit the file and add in url some variable like u said, still the changes does not take into effect instantly. tks

Comment: Do a phpinfo() and check if there is an APC or memcache section

Comment: look in the headers via `1.1 Varnish`! https://www.varnish-cache.org/

Comment: @rjdown, no it does not exist

Comment: @cmorrissey, yeah it looks like it is the problem, now the question is is it possible to disable it, just putting `Header append X-Varnish "disabled"` in htaccess does not work. thanks

Comment: how about `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if Varnish is set up correctly you can turn it off via PHP like so.

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate');
header('Expires: Tue, 04 Sep 2012 05:32:29 GMT');
```

Comment: you should talk to your host to figure out how you can resolve this

Comment: cmorrissey, thanks for ur efforts to help, yeah that is what I thought, thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Files being saved but php script did not change?

Try this in .htaccess - maybe because of new php-versions the apc cache is turned on by default:

php_flag opcache.enable Off